# Why Javascript functions don't work in the coded order?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm making a studying timer for the Pomodoro technique (25 min studying 5 min breaking). My timer works only when I called it once. If I call it twice or more, it count down to negative minutes and seconds. Moreover, when I called the studying timer first and the breaking timer later, it executes the breaking timer and skips the studying timer.

```
let timer;
function studying(){
    display_quote();
    var min = document.getElementById("study-min").value;
    document.getElementById("state").innerHTML = "STUDYING";
    var sec = min*60;
    timer = setInterval(function(){
        minn = Math.floor(sec/60);
        secc = sec%60;
        document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = getTime(minn,secc);
        sec-=1;
        if(sec==-1){
            clearInterval(timer);
            return;
        }
    },1000)
}
function breaking(){
    display_quote();
    min = document.getElementById("break-min").value;
    document.getElementById("state").innerHTML = "BREAKING";
    sec = min*60;
    timer = setInterval(function(){
        minn = Math.floor(sec/60);
        secc = sec%60;
        document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = getTime(minn,secc);
        sec-=1;
        if(sec==-1){
            clearInterval(timer);
            return;
        }
    },1000)
}
```

and here is the looping

```
for(var t=1;t<=loop;t++){
        studying();
        breaking();
    }
```

Comment: By using only global variables, you can't have two functions run at the same time.

Comment: I tried to fix it by creating two timer variables for studying and breaking and run the studying and breaking timer by if-else case. However, it still skips the studying and run only breaking. Did I make any mistakes?
```
for(var t=1;t<=2*loop;t++){
  if(t%2==1)
   studying();
  else
   breaking();
 }
```
```
let timer_studying,timer_breaking;

```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because callbacks inside `setInterval` are running "asynchronously", to solve this you could use [Promises](https://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_promise.asp) along with [Async/Await](https://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_async.asp). You could have a sweet code like this:

```js
let timer;

async function studying() {
    display_quote();
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var min = document.getElementById("study-min").value;
        document.getElementById("state").innerHTML = "STUDYING";
        var sec = min * 60;
        timer = setInterval(function () {
            minn = Math.floor(sec / 60);
            secc = sec % 60;
            document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = getTime(minn, secc);
            sec -= 1;
            if (sec == -1) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                resolve();
                return;
            }
        }, 1000);
    });

    return promise;
}

async function breaking() {
    display_quote();
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        min = document.getElementById("break-min").value;
        document.getElementById("state").innerHTML = "BREAKING";
        sec = min * 60;
        timer = setInterval(function () {
            minn = Math.floor(sec / 60);
            secc = sec % 60;
            document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = getTime(minn, secc);
            sec -= 1;
            if (sec == -1) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                resolve();
                return;
            }
        }, 1000);
    });

    return promise;
}

async function doJob() {
    let loop = 5;
    for (var t = 1; t <= loop; t++) {
        await studying();
        await breaking();
    }
}

doJob();
```

This time `studying()` is going to execute first and then `breaking()` in that order.

The magic here is done by `await` which basically means: "wait here until any asynchronous process inside `studying()` is complete", and `resolve()`: which indicates that the asynchronous process is complete and the control should be returned outside `studying()`